# Как стать веб-разработчиком за несколько месяцев

Tags: веб-программирование

Так получилось, что после универа и долгого изучения C++ меня не взяли ни а одну вакансиию C++разработчика. У нас их 6-7 штук и везде нужен большой опыт, и в то же время у нас 60-70 вакансий в вебе. Зашибись просто.

Есть цель: зарабатывать в вебе. Опыта работы в вебе нет. Что начать изучать и в каком порядке, чтобы через 2-4 месяца уже можно было подавать резюме на веб-вакансии?

Изучаю JS, ES5,6, HTML, CSS, React и LoDash. Что еще нужно? Как выучить необходимое быстро и качественно? Где можно брать идеи для мелких проектов и как определить, нужен ли в них, например, lodash, или хватит реакта и JSX?

Я изучаю веб-технологии довольно хаотично. Например, кроме всего, что я перечислил, я еще прохожу курс от Mail.Ru о бэкэнд-разработке и создании бэкэнд-приложений на питоне + DjangoMVC, что мне, скорее всего, не понадобится.

Comment: Может на мету? Много букв, жалко же)

Comment: Таки цель - зарабатывать в вебе или просто зарабатывать? Если будет предложена работа по cpp - откажетесь?

Comment: @vp_arth, не предлагают же. Недавно меня нашел человек из США и предложил удаленку. Требования у него невысокие. Давал мне задания в скайпе, попросил сделать трансляцию с монитора. Задания были в основном на умение гуглить и работатть с документацией по Qt после предварительных вопросов про всякие виртуальные деструкторы и функциональные фичи C++ типа лямбд, std::bind, transform/accumulate и прочее. Ответа нет три дня.

Comment: @vp_arth, не откажусь, конечно, но в местные компании меня не взяли. В одной просто промурыжили три недели. В геймдев-фирме после собеса говорили, что все нормально, можно готовить пакет документов и ждать ответа из Москвы, но в итоге уклончиво отказали: мол, вакансию они открыли, а слот создать забыли.

Answer (score 1):

Если имеешь цель зарабатывать на разработке сайтов, то сначала просто необходимо знать HTML, CSS и JS.
Весьма неплохо будет научиться работать с Bootstrap и jQuery.
Для CSS будет очень полезно научиться работать с препроцессорами (SASS, LESS, SCSS) (лично мне удобнее работать с SASS, но лучше узнать о них побольше, поработать немного с каждым препроцессором и окончательно решить, какой препроцессор будет лучше для вас), также сейчас в моду вошла технология Flexbox.
Работать будет очень удобно, если научиться работать с пакетным менеджером (NPM...). Также можно научиться работать с CMS - Wordpress, Joomla... (но могут потребоваться знания php (хотя бы поверхностные)). На первое время тебе хватит и этого. Если что, прикреплю "карту" для веб-разработчика (какие технологии учить, в каком порядке желательно и т.д.).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как красиво, что-то мне даже оффтоп удалять расхотелось)

Comment: Присоединяюсь к автору ответа, только адаптируй эту схему под багхантинг. (Не знаю, попробуй багхантинг, может понравится). Знаю лишь, что за 2 месяца нереально что-то выучить.